# RestKit: batch requesting of objects won't persist to database

Tags: ios, restkit

here is the problem:

I request for one object, it will fetched from the remote server and persisted to dataBase with no problem. here is how I do:

I have defined a route:

```
+ (RKRoute *)getRestMenuRoute
{
    return [RKRoute routeWithRelationshipName:@"rest_menu" objectClass:[Restaurant class] pathPattern:@"menu/:restaurantID" method:RKRequestMethodGET];
}
```

---

```
- (void)LoadRestaurantMenu:(Restaurant *)resturant withCompletionBlock:(completion)completionBlock
{

    [self getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:@"rest_menu" ofObject:resturant parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        completionBlock(YES, nil);
    }
    failure: ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         //creating a new error which contains HTTP status code
     }];
}
```

`self` is subclass of `RKObjectManager`

MenuMappingProvider:

```
RKEntityMapping *menuMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Menu" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    menuMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"menuID"];

    [menuMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                            @"Setting.MinOrder":@"minOrder" and more .....
                                                            }];

    NSDictionary *restaurantIDMapping = @{@"@metadata.routing.parameters.restaurantID": @"restaurantID"};
    [menuMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:restaurantIDMapping];
    [menuMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"restaurant" connectedBy:@{@"restaurantID":@"restaurantID"}];
```

but when I send batch request, restKit logs object retrieval and mapping successful but when I query for a restaurant menu, it will log `nil`! no object has been saved to dataBase.

here is my batch request:

```
- (void)syncRestaurantsMenuWithProgressCallBack:(progressCallback)progressCallBack
{
    [self enqueueBatchOfObjectRequestOperationsWithRoute:[HARouter getRestMenuRoute] objects:[Restaurant findAll] progress:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

        CGFloat progress = (CGFloat)numberOfFinishedOperations/(CGFloat)totalNumberOfOperations;
        progressCallBack(progress);
        NSLog(@"sync menu progress:%f", progress);
    } completion:^(NSArray *operations) {
        NSLog(@"all menus synced!");
    }];
}
```

RestKit log for every fetched object:

`restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:222 GET 'https://restaurant.com/menu/2176' (200 OK / 1 objects) [request=4.3484s mapping=0.0048s total=4.3588s]`

so whats your idea? what do you think? whats my problem?

**UPDATE:**

it seems when I batch queueing, `restaurant` relation from `Menu` entity to `Restaurant` entity won't stablished! I have defined a foreign key in `Menu` entity named `restaurantID` and I establish a connection from `Menu` to `Restaurant` with this foreign key. RestKit will set this foreign key from route metadata, then check Restaurants list to find a restaurant with this same Id then establish connection from menu to restaurant and visa versa.

RestKit CoreData Trace Log:

```
2015-12-07 14:11:47.290 MyApp[28491:16381752] T restkit.core_data:RKRelationshipConnectionOperation.m:193 Connecting relationship 'restaurant' with mapping: <RKForeignKeyConnectionDescription:0x7fe3715b4c20 connecting Relationship 'restaurant' from Entity 'Menu' to Destination Entity 'Restaurant' with attributes={
    restaurantID = restaurantID;
}>
2015-12-07 14:11:47.290 MyApp[28491:16381752] D restkit.core_data:RKRelationshipConnectionOperation.m:204 Connected relationship 'restaurant' to object '(null)'
```

**UPDATE 2**

first I get restaurants list, their basic info, then in the completion block I fetch menus. relation is one 2 one.
hence relation is one 2 one is this possible to NOT provide `identificationAttribute` for `Menu` entity in the Mapping?

link updated

[sample app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/my1k04jrsnh8box/RestKitSync.zip?dl=0)

Comment: How and when are you querying? Turn on trace logging.

Comment: thanks @Wain. if RestKi, then Wain... question updated

Comment: Is the relationship one-to-one or many-to-many ? Are you guaranteeing that all the menus and restaurants exist before the connections are processed ?

Comment: @Wain sample app provided.